# Objc headers - Fonction & protocols declaration

Tags: objective-c, header, protocols

I've been programming on swift for a few years now, but I've only recently tried to understand better Objc.
I am doing a small project on my own, using VIPER architecture. I have a sample .swift project that uses VIPER, and now I simply want to "translate" it to objc to learn about the syntax.

I am having some issues with the .h/.m files:
I don't know if I should declare my protocols inside a .m or .h file (separately), or inside a .h or a .m file (with the class whom they belong to).
I chose to put them all inside a .h file, and I created a .m file that imports it. But this seems really bad since the .m is empty.
Also, I get an error such as "Expected a type" when calling "MyViewController" as type in those protocols.

It is 100% sure that the issue is coming from the headers. I understand that ".h" must be imported from ".m" file to be compiled, and I also understand that we should not call the headers multiple time.
However, it feels like I get stuck when I have A.h/B.h files and I need to something from both A from B, and B from A. How do I get unstuck in that kind of situation?

My protocol.h looks like this:

```
@protocol SampleProtocol
+ (MyViewController*) createModule; // Error: Expected a type
- (void) pushToView: (UINavigationController*)navController;
@end
```

MyViewController.h looks like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property id<PresenterToRouterObjcProtocol> protocol;
@end
```

Thank you for your help, hopefully you'll enlight me on the piece I'm missing !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-C you typically house a class in its own .h and .m files. The *interface* goes in the .h and the *implementation* in the .m. You can think of the interface as a list of available messages without the implementation details and the implementation is then the actual implementation of it.

It dates back to C where you had .h and .c files. The .h file gives a definition of your function so that other code that uses it knows how to call it.

An Objective-C protocol is just an interface without an implementation and classes that implement the protocol must then provide the actual implementation. That said, a protocol will only have a .h file. A protocol will typically specify required and optional messages for the class to implement.

I hope this helps to understand, now how to solve your problem. It does not happen often, but sometimes it does happen that you need A from B while also needing B from A. Here I will assume A and B are classes, each with its own .h and .m file. The issue will be an issue in the header files.

You may have something like this

A.h

```
#import <Foundation...>
#import "B.h"

// Define class A
@interface A : NSObject

// Say this one has a property B
@property (nonatomic,strong) B * b;

@end
```

B.h

```
#import <Foundation...>
#import "A.h"

// Define class B
@interface B : NSObject

// Say this one has a property A
@property (nonatomic,strong) A * a;

@end
```

Now you have a chicken and egg situation. You can not define A wihtout knowing B and vice versa. You can solve this by just telling the compiler you will have a class of each type, as below.

A.h (B.h will be pretty similar)

```
#import <Foundation...>

// No more import of B.h, but define it for compiler in general terms
@class B; // Now compiler knows there will be a B

// Define class A
@interface A : NSObject

// This will work now as the compiler knows B is coming later
@property (nonatomic,strong) B * b;

@end
```

**EDIT**

Some specifics ... Above is the general answer, to be a bit more specific, you should not really put more than one class or protocol in a single header file. Each should have its own .h file. And to solve your problem remove the import and use

```
@class MyViewController;
```

in stead.

Comment: This is gold, you've answered everything! Im really glad I asked, you sir just made my day :)

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate this ... and just noted a typo in my answer! Of course ```@interface``` and ```@implementation``` do not take curly braces but rather ```@end```